# Does $[U\cup V] \cap [U\cup W] \subseteq [U\cup (V\cap W)]$ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $GF(q)$ be a finite field and $V:=(GF(q))^n$ be the $n$-dimensional vector space over $GF(q)$. If we have three linear subspaces $U,V,W$, does
\begin{align*}
 [U\cup V] \cap [U\cup W] \subseteq [U\cup (V\cap W)]
\end{align*}
hold? The other direction is trivial, but I am struggeling with this one, I cannot prove it nor find a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that the square brackets in the question mean "subspace spanned by". I also assume that the $V$ in the first sentence of the question is not intended to be the $V$ in the list $U,V,W$.

If those guesses are right, then the formula you asked about is not always true. For a small counterexample, work in a $2$-dimensional vector space, and let $U,V,W$ be three distinct $1$-dimensional subspaces. Then $U\cup V$ spans the whole plane, and so does $U\cup W$, so the left side of your formula is the whole plane. But $V\cap W$ contains only the origin, so the right side of your formula is only $U$.

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! I used exactly this counter example for another formula just before this and made a mistake when calculating the linear span hahaha thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$A\cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B)\cap (A \cup C)$ holds for arbitrary sets $A$, $B$, and $C$. The result you want always holds.

Edit:

For the direction you asked, suppose $x \in (A \cup B)\cap (A \cup C)$. This means $x \in A \cup B$ and $x \in A \cup C$. If $x \in A$, then $x \in A\cup (B \cap C)$. If $x \notin A$, then $x \in B$ and $x \in C$ so that $x \in B \cap C \subseteq A\cup (B \cap C)$.

Comment: Yeah I already thought that it is true, but how can I prove it? Your equation does not really help me. I tried taking an $x$ in the left side and two linear combinations $x=\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i y_i$ and $x=\sum_{i=1}^k \mu_i z_i$ and tried to show, that the $y_i$ and $z_i$ would have to be in $U$ or in $V\cap W$ but I did not really succeed.

Comment: I wrote down a detailed version.